# How to properly indicate operator notation on the Smoluchowski equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, differential-operators

in the case of homgeneous temperature $T$,drag  coefficient $\gamma$ and conservative force $F(r)=-\nabla V(r)$, the well known Smoluchowski equation is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P(r,t)}{\partial t}&=\frac{1}{\gamma}\nabla\cdot\big[P(r,t)\nabla V(r)+kT\nabla P(r,t)\big].
\end{align}
Usually can be written in a more condensed form
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P(r,t)}{\partial t}&=\mathcal{L}P(r,t),
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the corresponding evolution opertaor.

If one writes the Smoluchoski equation in this way, what is the proper way to define the evolution operator?

I simple wrote it as

\begin{align}\label{Eq:Smoluchowski}
\mathcal{L}&=\frac{1}{\gamma}\nabla\cdot\big[\nabla V(r)+kT\nabla\big],
\end{align}

yet I was told by a peer reviewer that my notation is ambiguous and can be misinterpreted
as

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}P(r,t)=\frac{1}{\gamma}\nabla\cdot\big[\nabla (V(r)P(r,t))+kT\nabla P(r,t)\big],
\end{align}

In my current work, I refer back to $\mathcal{L}$ and also use it to operate over other variables aside $P(r,t)$ multiple times,  thus I need to clarify its definition and avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make the order of multiplication/differentiation more clear is to distribute the divergence. I'll use $\Delta=\nabla\cdot\nabla$ to denote the Laplacian.
$$
\mathcal{L}P=\frac{1}{\gamma}\nabla\cdot\left(P\nabla V+kT\nabla P\right) \\
=\frac{1}{\gamma}\left[(\Delta V)P+(\nabla V)\cdot\nabla P+kT\Delta P\right] \\
=\frac{1}{\gamma}\left[(\Delta V)+(\nabla V)\cdot\nabla+kT\Delta\right]P \\
$$
And thus we can write $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{\gamma}[(\Delta V)+(\nabla V)\cdot\nabla+kT\Delta]$.

That said, there's nothing wrong with defining $\mathcal{L}$ by defining how it acts on functions, i.e. using the expression $\mathcal{L}P=\frac{1}{\gamma}\nabla\cdot\left(P\nabla V+kT\nabla P\right)$ as the defintion of $\mathcal{L}$.